# Using ES6 or Vue 2, is it possible to import once and use across multiple other imports?

Tags: inheritance, mvvm, model, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I'm building a data heavy application in Vue.js 2.

I would like to use models (/classes) for my data as it comes in very well defined objects and found some fine frameworks for this.

My problem is that there are quite a few types of models and they are internally dependent through both use and inheritance.
I would like to minimise the number of places I import each model but global inclusion doesn't seem to be possible or viable.

I have made a [demo of my intent](https://plnkr.co/edit/uezZdd?p=preview), as [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as possible – these are the highlights:

**index.html** (relevant part only, see the demo for context)

```
import {BaseModel} from "./base-model.js"
import {BaseDataModel} from "./base-data.js"

let model = new BaseDataModel();
```

**base-model.js**

```
export {BaseModel};

class BaseModel {
    routes() {
        return { fetch: "/" + this.options.path + "/" + this.id }
    }
}
```

**base-data.js**

```
export {BaseDataModel};

class BaseDataModel extends BaseModel {
    defaults() {
        return { id: null, navn: "" }
    }

    options() {
        return { path: "" }
    }
}
```

This fails when including `base-data.js` as it doesn't have the `BaseModel` class in its scope, giving this message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: BaseModel is not defined

What am I missing? Is there a simple, neat, smart, basic, general, clever, or otherwise usable solution to only including each model (and collection) once?

**EDIT:**
I know the concept of modules is to have a self-contained piece of logic that satisfies a specific purpose. I'm not trying to break this, but gradually enhance similar value objects that represent slightly different entities in our system.

These are closely related but would benefit quite a bit from inheritance, but still differ in properties, validation, and business logic. The above examples are simplified to the point where the problem is just showing its face — the actual inheritance tree is more along these lines (and will grow):

```
BaseModel
  |
  +- BaseData
  |    |
  |    +- Type
  |    +- Status
  |    +- Material
  |
  +- BasePerson
  |    |
  |    +- Owner
  |    +- Creator
  |
  +- BaseObject
       |
       +- Artwork
       |    |
       |    +- Painting
       |    +- Sculpture
       |
       +- Surrounding
            |
            +- Showcase
            +- Building
```

And of course any derivative of `BaseObject` can have derivatives of `BaseModel` in its properties.

This is fine and all, but as there may be several levels of inheritance and pretty much any level can be referenced, I would have to import most other classes in every other and remember to update it all when something is added, changed, or removed — importing all the classes in some sort of global way would make that problem go away, which would make me happy even if it's not exactly the right way of doing it.

Comment: You need to import anything you're going to use in a module. Otherwise it's not self-contained.

Comment: I would ask what the use case is for trying to completely decouple your parent and child classes? Are you planning on having multiple forms of `BaseModel` that you can switch out at need? It sounds like you're trying for a form of polymorphism which Javascript doesn't need as any data can be redefined as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have updated my question to try and answer your comments and hope it makes better sense now :)
It's not that I couldn't do it all with plain objects, but going forward it will easily become messy and this approach seem to encapsulate things in a way that suites this purpose better :)